# Dynamic JQuery Dropdown doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create 2 dynamic dropdowns. The second dropdown should change its options depending on what i chosen in the first dropdown. I have found a great example on here already that works on JSFiddle.

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/tony089/8hbcP/51/

HTML:

```
<select id="us_state"></select>
<select id="city_name"></select>
```

JQUERY:

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
var data = {
"State 1": ["City 1", "City 2"],
"State 2": ["City 3", "City 4"],
"State 3": ["City 5", "City 6", "City 7"]
};

var $states = $("#us_state").on("change", function() {
  var cities = $.map(data[this.value], function(city) {
  return $("<option />").text(city);
});

$("#city_name").empty().append(cities);
});
for (var state in data) {
$("<option />").text(state).appendTo($states);
}
$states.change();
$('#us_state').multiselect('refresh');
$('#city_name').multiselect('refresh');
});

</script>
<?
```

When i take the code above the way it is and try to run it in my HTML, the first dropdown is populated like it's supposed to be and the second dropdown too, but when i click on the second option on the first dropdown (which is supposed to cause the second dropdown to change its values/options), the second dropdown is not updated with the correct values and maintains the values of the first option.

This is how my HTML looks like:

```
$row1 = "
    <tr>
      <td colspan='1' align = 'left';>
        Google Search:<br>
        <select name='filters[]' id='filters' style='width:180px;' size='6'>
        " . $filter_dropdown . "
        </select>
      </td>
      <td colspan='1' align = 'left';>
         Choose State:<br>
        <select id='us_state'>
        </select>
      <br/>
      </td>
      <td colspan='1' align = 'left';>
         Choose City:<br>
        <select id='city_name'></select>
      </td>
      <td colspan='1' align = 'left';>
      </td>       
    </tr>";
```

Can anyone point me as to where i'm making a mistake on here? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you got the jQuery you use? Or have you used the example?
Are you able to show us a link to your page that doesn't work? :)

**EDIT:**

This worked for me (your HTML):

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
     <table>
        <tr>
          <td colspan='1' align = 'left';>
            Google Search:<br>
            <select name='filters[]' id='filters' style='width:180px;' size='6'>

            </select>
          </td>
          <td colspan='1' align = 'left';>
             Choose State:<br>
            <select id='us_state'>
            </select>
          <br/>
          </td>
          <td colspan='1' align = 'left';>
             Choose City:<br>
            <select id='city_name'></select>
          </td>
          <td colspan='1' align = 'left';>
          </td>       
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var data = {
    "State 1": ["City 1", "City 2"],
    "State 2": ["City 3", "City 4"],
    "State 3": ["City 5", "City 6", "City 7"]
};


var $states = $("#us_state").on("change", function() {
    var cities = $.map(data[this.value], function(city) {
        return $("<option />").text(city);
    });
    $("#city_name").empty().append(cities);
});

for (var state in data) {
    $("<option />").text(state).appendTo($states);
}

$states.change();
$('#us_state').multiselect('refresh');
$('#city_name').multiselect('refresh');
});

</script>

  </html>
```

Comment: I used the exact example as the one i've posted, one-one. The page is password secured so i cant provide a link to it.

Comment: I mean a link to the page wouldnt help since its password secured.

Comment: Added some code above. I took your HTML and their jQuery and seemed to work for me? Did you include a reference to the jQuery library?

Comment: Hi Ali, Thanks for your reply. You're tip proved really helpful and actually solved the problem.I had included a reference to the jQuery library 1.8.3. However, when i include the one you just included (2.1.1) the dynamic dropdowns work like a charm, the only issue is that my entire page and other dropdowns are really messed up then. Is it unthinkable that the earlier versions don't support dynamic dropdowns? 
Alot of other pages here depend on the 1.8.3 inclusion and i would undo a lot of work if i decided to go with the 2.1.1

Comment: Ah ok - glad I was of some help! Assume I can't get the accepted answer tick lol... in what way are they messed up?

Comment: You get the tick mate, no worries. Since i globally included the jQuery Library 1.8.3, its apparently conflicting with me including a second library locally (?). Why am i unable to use 1.8.3?